# Accessing Cloud Storage from Cloud ML Engine during prediction

Tags: tensorflow, google-cloud-storage, google-cloud-ml

I am trying to build an image classifier, that will recognise the class for a test image based on a similiarity measure between the test image and a dataset of labeled images. Basically, I want to use a KNN classifier that takes as input the bottleneck features of a pretrained CNN model. 
I would like to store this dataset of labeled images (the bottleneck features) in a seperate bucket in the Google Cloud Storage and give my model access to this dataset during prediction, since the file size of my saved model would be to big, when adding this dataset to the saved model (Google restricts the file size to 250MB). Unfortunately, I can't find a way to access a bucket from a SavedModel. Does anyone have any idea how to solve this?

Answer (score 0):

Code running on the service currently only has access to public GCS buckets. You can contact us offline (cloudml-feedback@google.com) and we may be able to increase your file size quota.